# Modificar base de datos tras publicar post wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Estoy trabajando con Custom Post Type, creando clases y cursos. Cuando el curso está programado como borrador no me deja seleccionarlo como padre de las clases.

¿Cómo puedo hacer un UPDATE para especificarle el padre a nivel de ID?

Es decir, al pulsar en "Programar clase", automáticamente se modifique en la BBDD el ID de su curso padre.

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo estoy haciendo por funciones de WordPress. He desarrollado la siguiente:

`function guardar_padre($post_id){
    $tipo_post = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ($tipo_post != 'curso'){
        return;
    } else {
        $id_padre = get_field(pertenece);
        if($id_padre != 0){
            wp_update_post(
                array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_parent' => $id_padre
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
add_action('post_updated','guardar_padre');`

El problema es que cuando le doy a actualizar post, se queda cargando, como si entrara en un bucle infinito que nunca acaba. Aún así, si consulto la BBDD el cambio se ha aplicado correctamente.

¿Qué falla en mi código que lo hace entrar en ese bucle infinito?

Comment: El problema con este código es el hook que elegiste. post_updated, se dispara después de que se realizó la actualización de un post y como en tu código actualizás nuevamente el post, el proceso entra en un loop infinito. Te recomendaría que mires el hook pre_post_update para lo que querés hacer.